# Memory Leak with UIBezierPath in swift

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, uibezierpath

I am working on an app that draws waveforms in a window that slides in and out of the main view. I find that if I open the sliding view several times the app begins to slow down. I have discovered that drawing the waveforms with a UIBezierPath is slowing down my app. I'm wondering if there is something that I need to do to terminate the current UIBezierPath and avoid a memory leak. Any suggestions or advice is appreciated I'm not super familiar with using UIBezierPath. Thanks in advance for the help!!!

```
import UIKit

class WaveView: UIView {
    enum WaveType{
        case sin
        case triangle
        case square
        case noise
        case sawtooth
    }
    var waveType: WaveType = .sin { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    var color = UIColor.black { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    
    var isSelected = false {
        didSet {
            let tempColor: UIColor = self.backgroundColor!
            self.backgroundColor = color
            color = tempColor
        }
    }
    
    private var labelColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let middle: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height
        let graphWidth: CGFloat = 0.6
        let amplitude: CGFloat = 0.2
        let midOrigin = CGPoint(x: width * (1 - graphWidth) / 2, y: height * 0.50)
        
        switch waveType {
        case .sin:
            path.move(to: midOrigin)
            for angle in stride(from: 5.0, through: 360.0, by: 5.0) {
                let x = midOrigin.x + CGFloat(angle/360.0) * width * graphWidth
                let y = midOrigin.y - CGFloat(sin(angle/180.0 * Double.pi)) * height * amplitude
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            }
        case .triangle:
            let d = rect.width * 0.2
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x, y: middle.y - d))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x + d, y: middle.y + d))
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x, y: middle.y - d))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x - d, y: middle.y + d))
        case .square:
            let d = rect.width * 0.2
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x - d, y: middle.y + d))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x - d/3, y: middle.y + d))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x - d/3, y: middle.y - d))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x + d/3, y: middle.y - d))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x + d/3, y: middle.y + d))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x + d, y: middle.y + d))
        case.sawtooth:
            let d = rect.width * 0.2
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x - d, y: middle.y + d))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x + d, y: middle.y - d))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: middle.x + d, y: middle.y + d))
        case .noise:
            path.move(to: midOrigin)
            for angle in stride(from: 3.0, through: 360.0, by: 3.0) {
                let x = midOrigin.x + CGFloat(angle/360.0) * width * graphWidth
                let y = midOrigin.y - CGFloat(Float.random(in: -1..<1)) * height * amplitude
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            }
        }
        
        color.setStroke()
        path.lineCapStyle = .round
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make the path instance a class member variable - just declare a local  UIBezierPath variable in your draw() method.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    // etc.
}
```

This will ensure the path instructions and data used for one draw() invocation is freed up.